# How to resolve the no-undef error for setTimeout

Tags: reactjs, eslintrc

My code

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // we add a hidden class to the card and after 700 ms we delete it and the transition appears
    this.timeOutFunction = setTimeout(
      function () {
        this.setState({cardAnimaton: ""});
      }.bind(this),
      700
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeOutFunction);
    this.timeOutFunction = null;
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (this.state.logged_in) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }
```

I turned on the following in my `.eslintrc`

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
       "no-set-state": "off",
       "react/no-multi-comp":  [1, { "ignoreStateless": true }]
    },

    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 6,
      "sourceType": "module",
      "ecmaFeatures": {
          "jsx": true,
          "modules": true
      }
  },
  "globals": {
    "localStorage": true,
    "fetch": true
},
  "settings": {
    "react": {
        "pragma": "React",
        "version": "16.4.1"
    }
    }
}
```

And I get the following warnings

```
setTimeout is not defined (no-undef)
clearTimeout is not defined (no-undef)
```

How do I resolve this warning?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The issue is your [environment](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments) in `.eslintrc` is not configured.

***Each environment brings with it a certain set of predefined global variables.***

You can configure it for **browser** [your React/Redux/JavaScript Code] & **node** [Webpack and build related code].

```
"env": {
  "browser": true,
  "node": true
},
```

Comment: Works! Thank you :)